# Is Stack Overflow owned by the jQuery Foundation?

Tags: discussion

The [jQuery Support](https://jquery.org/support/) web page says:

> The following resources are provided by the jQuery community free of charge.
>       jQuery Learning Center
>       Try jQuery
>       IRC/Chat
>       Forums
>       Stack Overflow

I was surprised to be told that Stack Overflow is provided by the jQuery community. I can find no mention of it on the ["About Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) page.

Perhaps someone from Stack Overflow would like to contact the jQuery Foundation about that statement, or just let me know that it isn't a problem.

**Update:** [Sagar V](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350747/is-stack-overflow-owned-by-the-jquery-foundation?noredirect=1#comment482135_350749) has kindly made a Github pull request for an update to the page in question. Hopefully there'll be a useful outcome.

**The end.** Sagar V's edit was accepted.

Comment: I guess they mean "Support on Stack Overflow (when using the `jquery` tag)".

Comment: @Tom What we *guess* they mean and what they actually say are two different things.

Comment: They also didn't invent IRC, Chat or Forums, so ....

Comment: Given that the link leads to the jQuery tag, it seems pretty obvious that they mean providing support in the tag rather than owning a $40+ million dollar private company. Not sure if there's anything for the team to do about here.

Comment: Just the same as Google Maps API [get started](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/) page - _"**Stack Overflow** Ask a question under the [tag:google-maps] tag."_

Comment: I see you're doubtful of the credibility of the jQuery Foundation. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the jQuery *community* is providing the resource of jQuery answers on StackOverflow. Nowhere do they say the jQuery Foundation.

Comment: That was written by a programmer, not a lawyer or "support specialist" or a manager.  Notable how it makes it instantly credible :)

Comment: @AlonEitan The reference to SO is in a distinctly different area and it doesn't look like they're laying any claim to SO. And I expect they got permission, if required, from SO to use the logo.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you clarify what you meant by "that", please?

Comment: @BoltClock I would use jQuery but I don't like spending money and I hear it needs a lot of `$`'s...

Comment: @JonClements 1) It doesn't cost anything unless you've used jQuery 2.x cos the client said they have no older versions of IE in use and then you find out they have and you have to change to jQuery 1.x. 2) Ha ha :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton: he made a joke.... it needs alot of `$` >.< refering to the syntax I'd assume (o jquerry def) not to the product.

Comment: @dhein Please see item 2) in my reply :) Also, not enough upvotes for BoltClock's reference to [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/232762).

Comment: No, but Stack Exchange [might be sponsored by jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/244695)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The resource means the QA's which are available in Stack Overflow.

The community means everyone using jQuery. They logically played.

Because the Questions and answers are provided by the users of jQuery and so, they mentioned them *The Community*.

And the Link points to the info of [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

[image]

You can see similar links on Google devs' which saying **Ask for help on Stack Overflow**

## Update

I made a Pull Request and they merged it.

Now it is changed to Stack Overflow Posts

Check it [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery.org/pull/132)

Comment: By your final paragraph, the jQuery Foundation page should say "jQuery on Stack Overflow".

Comment: They should. The site is on github. you can edit it and give a pull request

Comment: The point of Andrew's post is that while we know what's meant by that page - the wording is just a little strange. The key point being: *Perhaps someone from Stack Overflow would like to contact the jQuery Foundation about that statement, or just let me know that it isn't a problem.*

Comment: It may be a mistake made by any of the contributer. I made a PR along with a link to this post